# How to set from value while using mutt command in ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu

How to set from value while sending mail via mutt command currently it's taking 
Unix username and also how to make people cc while sending mail via mutt command

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This page is **really** helpful [MAN](http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html).

There are number of usefull tutorials:
 - [One](http://nongeekshandbook.blogspot.com/2009/02/mutt-email-client-that-sucks-less.html)
 - [Two](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/get-started-with-mutt)
 - [Wiki](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide)

It takes email from environment variable EMAIL, so you can run it:
`>EMAIL=... mutt -c "CC email address" ...`

P.S. The question belongs to superuser.com.

Comment: but were should i put this